# Unable to rectify the logic of grabbing next page links to make the execution faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to create a script using `concurrent.futures` to make the execution faster. The site link that I've used within this script is a placeholder but the logic is the same.

I'm trying to let the script parse the target links from it's landing page and then use those newly scraped links to fetch the required information from their inner pages. There is a pagination button in the landing page which leads to the next pages. `FYI, there is no highest page number associated with the next page button, so I've to stick with next page link like the way I've shown below.`

***The way the following script is going for the next pages is slowing the process down.***

Here is what I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        target_link = base.format(item.get("href"))
        yield target_link

    next_page = soup.select_one("a[rel='next']:contains('Next')")
    if next_page:
        next_page_link = base.format(next_page.get("href"))
        yield from get_links(next_page_link)

def get_info(target_link):
    res = requests.get(target_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").get_text(strip=True)
    user_name =  soup.select_one(".user-details[itemprop='author'] > a").get_text(strip=True)
    return user_name,title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = "https://stackoverflow.com{}"
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        for r in [executor.submit(get_info, item) for item in get_links(url)]:
            print(r.result())
```

> What type of change should I bring about within the script to make it run faster?

Comment: why you are not using scrapy?

Comment: I've already used scrapy and asyncio before posting this question. Yeah, they both are very fast. However, I'm trying to figure out an ideal way when it is about making the execution faster while using concurrent.futures.

Answer (score 1):

There are several changes you can make:

1. Increase the thread pool size.
2. Use a `requests` `Session` object since you are making all your GET requests to the same website.
3. Instead of creating a list of `Future` instances, you will start getting output immediately if you use a generator expression.
4. I have also added code to test for the presence or not of expected fields. It turns out that after some number of requests, StackOverflow stops honoring the requests with a "Too Many Requests" error page and you get no useful data back as I painfully found out. So I suspect your goal of increasing speed wil lbe ultimately hampered by this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def get_links(session, link):
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        target_link = base.format(item.get("href"))
        yield target_link

    next_page = soup.select_one("a[rel='next']:contains('Next')")
    if next_page:
        next_page_link = base.format(next_page.get("href"))
        yield from get_links(session, next_page_link)

def get_info(session, target_link):
    res = session.get(target_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    #title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").get_text(strip=True)
    title_elem = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] > a")
    title = title_elem.get_text(strip=True) if title_elem else 'title is missing'
    #user_name =  soup.select_one(".user-details[itemprop='author'] > a").get_text(strip=True)
    user_name_elem =  soup.select_one(".user-details[itemprop='author'] > a")
    user_name = user_name_elem.get_text(strip=True) if user_name_elem else 'user name is missing'
    return user_name,title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base = "https://stackoverflow.com{}"
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

    with requests.Session() as session:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
            for r in (executor.submit(partial(get_info, session), item) for item in get_links(session, url)):
                print(r.result())
```